# Set default wallpaper for a local Windows default user profile used by all users of a domain

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization, windows-domain

I want to put a wallpaper by default in a local user profile for Windows that everyone is the same wallpaper.

The local profile Windows is loaded by default when a user logs on to the Windows domain, it allows a single profile management for all users.

It is stored locally on all computers on the network.

The idea is to set this wallpaper in a configuration file located in the user profile by default.

But we do not find any file to define what change wallpaper.

Currently, the screen automatically goes black ...